Can't get rid of questions restriction
I updated all of my questions, and they all follow the guidelines.
I also tried my best to update the deleted questions I have. Obviously I can't provide code or context on a 4 year old question. And I have a question that wasn't on topic and got deleted.
All my last questions have been answered and I managed to have successful discussions with other users.
I don't know what to do. Almost all the questions follow the guidelines. Is there a way to know what my questions are missing? Since I can't find any problem with my questions, I would like to know at least what the problem is.

Did you undelete the questions that you had previously self deleted? I only see 4 questions on your account right now, so it's rather difficult to give any general feedback about the question content.

"Obviously I can't provide code or context on a 4 year old question." - you can, actually. In fact, one good approach to writing a [mre] is to start completely from scratch. It'll take more work, but if you really want to remove the restrictions, that's just something that you'll have to do.

Forgot that MRE isn't a magic link on MSO. The proper link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You probably need 2 accounts, one for questions that will be totally voted down through the floor, and another account where you actually help other people with answers.

@steb Question and answer bans are separate IIRC, so OP probably doesn't need two separate accounts. Also, creating a second account is seen as a form of circumvention and can get your second account question-blocked.

@steb what Anerdw said is correct: your advice is likely to be counterproductive regarding automatic question blocks, and could even lead to manual suspensions from moderators.  Please don't advise people to try to evade system restrictions in ways that violate the rules.

@lagicarus Our tooling suggests to me that you are no longer blocked from asking questions.

The edits you've provided to the four non-deleted questions are a good start, but some of them don't really address the central problems with their questions. A few things stood out to me:

How to solve "implode(): Invalid arguments passed"?

This question was closed, which indicates that the community thought it needed improvements. If a question of yours is ever closed, that doesn't mean it should never be answered! It means you should edit it to address the specific problems, then request reevalution.
This question in particular was indicated as "needing debugging details." This generally means you need a minimal, reproducible example (in addition to any non-code steps needed to reproduce your problem) and/or information about the current results of your code. Under what conditions is implode() throwing an error? Is there any other code that's needed to reproduce your problem? (Your HTML code in particular looks like it could use a little more.) Did you take a look at the comments and edit your question to include the information they asked for? All of those things could help make your question easier to answer and more useful for other users.

How do i solve 'Error Cannot add foreign key constraint'?

This one was caused by a typo ("Professor"-"Professors" mismatch), so I'm honestly not sure how it can be improved. Cutting down on your code sample is a good step towards a minimal, reproducible example, but it doesn't make the question more useful.

How to solve "The method nextInt() is undefined for the type Scanner"?

As you noted in a comment, the problem was that you had defined another class named Scanner. But you don't show that definition in your code sample, which makes your question really hard to answer. To improve this question, you should provide a minimal, reproducible example.
You also have large quantities of code in your sample that are not needed to reproduce your example, and the lack of indentation makes it harder to parse. A better, more minimal version of what you have might look like this:
package TercerCas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeraActivitat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nombre;
        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);

        nombre = ent.nextInt();
        System.out.println(nombre);

        ent.close();
    }
}

But without the aforementioned other code, this change alone wouldn't resolve the question's most significant issue.

General notes

It seems like you often answer questions in the comments. Try to develop a habit of doing so in an edit instead. Avoid the common practice of adding a big "EDIT" block at the bottom of your post - instead, incorporate them into your question body so the additional information flows naturally.
You also have a couple of minor grammar and spelling mistakes in your questions. That's to be expected, and nobody will punish you for that! But give this guide a look, whether or not you're a native speaker: Advice for non-native English speakers.

Thank you for your response and for taking the time to do it. I am aware of some major flaws in these questions. The ones that are deleted are not any better. The main thing is I do not have those files anymore and I can not provide the needed data/debugging/examples, I could come up with some "fake" code that gets that problem, but I don't think that would be usefull at all.

@Iagicarus It might be! As long as you can faithfully and succinctly reproduce the error, seeing your code, errors, and other information might help someone else with the same problem. It really comes down to "how much do I want this question ban lifted?" The more this matters to you, the more effort you should put into improving the posts you have, and vice versa.
